# Targeted cloned element for GSAP timeline to run only when clicked

Tags: javascript, clone, gsap

Define a GSAP animation to run for a specific target. Currently, all of the tile's content fades out, but should only be for the one clicked. `Check out the codepen`

Update: I have solved my issue by targeting the cloned element: by adding

```
 let cloneAnimation = clone.querySelector('.tile .inner-content');
        gsap.to(cloneAnimation, {
            duration: 2.0,
            opacity: 0
        })
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Syntrix/pen/rNwgGWR)

Comment: Don't use a generic selector string. Use a selector scoped to the tile that you want to animate.

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking. It needs to be generic because in my project there could be 100’s of tiles. Every thing is working fine except being able to target the cloned tile using a GSAP timeline.

Comment: You can use .querySelectorAll with any element as your starting element, not just the document. Do that

Comment: All sorted and works perfectly now. Check out the codepen. Thanks